# why Quantity is not updating along with the total price in cart page in magento 1.9.2?

Tags: magento, cart

```
I have used the follow code in checkout/cart page in my theme:
<?php foreach($this->getItems() as $_item): ?>
                   <hr>
              </hr> <?php echo $this->getItemHtml($_item) ?>

                <?php endforeach ?>

<?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->toHtml() ?>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('form_before') ?>
     <form action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/cart/updatePost') ?>" method="post">

        <?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>
      <fieldset>
<input type="hidden" name="form_key" value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey(); ?>"/>

  <button type="submit" name="update_cart_action"  value="update_qty" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Update Shopping Cart')); ?>" class="btnn4"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Update Shopping Cart'); ?></span></span></button>

<script type="text/javascript">decorateTable('shopping-cart-table')</script>
        </fieldset> 
    </form>
```

checkout/cart/item/default.phtml is remain same as it is in the base.When I adding some quantity in my cart page ..after clicking update button the page is reloading but the multiplied value with the quantity not showing and also quantity is remaining same.